# Ajax call to display a PHP variable

Tags: php, jquery

I feel as if I'm making a noob mistake here, but it's annoying the hell out of me so I guess I'll post!

I'm trying to get `message` in the php array to be logged to the console. What actually happens is, data returns nothing, message returns 'success' and data.message is undefined.

JavaScript:

```
var message = '';
jQuery.ajax({
    url: '/dir/myfile.php',
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data: { message : message },
    error: function(xhr, text, thrown){
        console.log('error');
    },
    success: function(data, message, text, xhr){

        if(data.message){
            console.log('data exists');
        } else if(message){
            console.log(message);
        }else{
            console.log('no data');
        }
    },
})
```

PHP:

```
$output = array(
    'code' => 1,
    'message' => 'Please work!'
);
echo json_encode($output);
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen, and what happens instead?

Comment: what is your error? "If it's not obvious" ,. How is this obvious?

Comment: In addition to the above questions, when you navigate directly to `*yourdomainhere*/dir/myfile.php`, do you *see* the JSON output you're expecting it to hand back to the AJAX request?

Comment: use `jQuery.post` to post your data

Comment: look at the jquery documentation instead of copy and pasting obsolete code from online sources. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Why @prash? That's just a wrapper for $.ajax?

Comment: you may also need to set the content type of the php script: `header('Content-type: application/json')`

Comment: @Liam, Agree. When posting data to server, the wrapper jQuery.post is often used. not necessary though.

Answer (score 2):

According to https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/, the prototype of the success callback should be :

```
Function(PlainObject data, String textStatus, jqXHR jqXHR)
```

Anyway, you should not do a test like this :

```
if (data) { ... } else if (msg) { ... }
```

Because your message is your data !

What you want looks like that :

```
if (data) { console.log(data.code) ; console.log(data.message) ; }
```

Comment: well, data returns nothing. So the alert for data doesn't get output. msg exists though and returns 'success'.

Comment: you should also be using the `Promise` object returned by `.ajax` call. Scroll down on https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ to see how to use `done()` and `fail()` and `always()`

Comment: If data returns nothing, but success is call, it means the PHP script is called but output  no data (or no json data). Check what your script outputs when you go to /dir/myfile.php, if you see something try to set the header content type with a `header('Content-type: application/json')`.

Comment: okay, tried that.
Changed to POST and it returned the JSON fine inside the PHP file. I then turned the JS back on and it went back to returning data.